# Keeping submit button disabled until dynamically created required fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I want to keep the submit button disabled until the required fields are being filled.

Firstly , 
I found some questions about this issue but the problem was i have some required fields and not required fields also i am creating these fields dynamically. 
Here is an example:

```
<input type="text" id="releaseartist" name="releaseartist" required="true" placeholder="Required Field"/>
```

Also i have input like that , this is how i am creating them dynamically,

```
var trackartistinput = document.createElement('input');
trackartistinput.setAttribute('type', "text");
trackartistinput.setAttribute('id', "trackartist" + i);
trackartistinput.setAttribute('name', "trackartist");
trackartistinput.setAttribute("required", true);
trackartistinput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Required Field");
trackartistinput.setAttribute("class", "required");
```

And this is my submit button :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" id="form-submit" onclick="return myConfirm();" />
```

Comment: Just write a validation for the submit button.

Comment: @Ducaz035, as mentioned above, any reason you can just write a validator that will check if the required fields have been filled when the submit button is clicked...?

Comment: Also, if you really wanted, you could add a onChange type event handler with each of the required fields when your generating them dynamically, and that event could check whether all the required fields have been filled

Comment: I can add a event handler of course, i am wondering how can i check all of the input fields that are required. i need a loop for them. Can you show me a snippet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the count of required fields added in the document so far and based on the counts you can set the property of submit button to disabled or enabled.

you can count required class components as follow:

```
var numItems = $('.required').length
```

EDIT

to check if all the required class elements are filled you can check as follow:

```
var required_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('required');
var allfilled=true;
for (var i = 0; i < required_ele.length; ++i) {
    var item = required_ele[i];  
    if(item.value.length==0){
      allfilled=false;
    }
}
if(allfilled){
   document.getElementById("form-submit").disabled = false;
}
else{
  document.getElementById("form-submit").disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get this answer correctly i guess , what will i suppose to do after checking the required fields ? How will i determine them if they are filled or not ?

Comment: you can find the required component count and using that you can make submit button enabled/disabled check edit of question

Comment: I am sorry for that but still i didn't get how to use this information

Comment: Okay now , it makes sense i will  take them as an array by doing document.getElementsByClassName('required'); , Thank you so much  i will try that asap.

Comment: glad it helped to you.

Answer (score 2):

- Start with button having disabled attribute set.
- Add change event listener to form element (assuming that is the parent of all input
  elements)
- in change handler check if all required fields are filled, if yes, enable submit button

This work well even if user remove value entered in required field later, submit button will become disabled again

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm , this helps with the overview of the solution but i still have problem with  "check if all required fields are filled" this part.

Comment: @Ducaz035 There are numerous that can help you with the validation itself. [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) may be a good start.