# Enable save button when all the required fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code to enable save button when all the required fields are filled. But, for some reason it is not working for the "audience" & "messagetemplate". Save button gets enabled even if these 2 fields are not filled.

```js
const saveCommunicationButton = document.getElementById("save-communication-button")
const audience = document.getElementById("communicationdata_communication_audience")
const messageTemplate = document.getElementById("communicationdata_message_template")
const communicationName = document.getElementById("communicationdata_communication_name")
const description = document.getElementById("communicationdata_communication_description")
const campaignGroup = document.getElementById("communicationdata_campaign_group")
const campaignCategory = document.getElementById("communicationdata_campaign_category")
const campaignType = document.getElementById("communicationdata_campaign_type")
const campaignFrequency = document.getElementById("communicationdata_campaign_frequency")
const campaignDescription = document.getElementById("communicationdata_campaign_description")
// this is to check if the input for all 3 is valid.  if so, enable saveCampaignButton.
const checkEnableButton = () => {
  saveCommunicationButton.disabled = !(
    audience.value &&
    messageTemplate.value &&
    communicationName.value &&
    description.value &&
    campaignGroup.value &&
    campaignCategory.value &&
    campaignType.value &&
    campaignFrequency.value &&
    campaignDescription.value !== ""
  )
}
audience.addEventListener("change", checkEnableButton)
messageTemplate.addEventListener("change", checkEnableButton)
communicationName.addEventListener("change", checkEnableButton)
description.addEventListener("change", checkEnableButton)
campaignGroup.addEventListener("change", checkEnableButton)
campaignCategory.addEventListener("change", checkEnableButton)
campaignType.addEventListener("change", checkEnableButton)
campaignFrequency.addEventListener("change", checkEnableButton)
campaignDescription.addEventListener("change", checkEnableButton)
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Format your code properly, and show us the HTML this is supposed to operate on as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keeping submit button disabled until dynamically created required fields are filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420378/keeping-submit-button-disabled-until-dynamically-created-required-fields-are-fil)

Answer (score 0):

This is not how to test not not equal

```
audience.value &&
messageTemplate.value &&
communicationName.value &&
description.value &&
campaignGroup.value &&
campaignCategory.value &&
campaignType.value &&
campaignFrequency.value &&
campaignDescription.value !== ""
```

Why not add `required` to each field, then the form cannot be submitted

Alternatively use an array of IDs

```js
const disable = ["save-communication-button", "communicationdata_communication_audience", "communicationdata_message_template", "communicationdata_communication_name", "communicationdata_communication_description", "communicationdata_campaign_group", "communicationdata_campaign_category", "communicationdata_campaign_type", "communicationdata_campaign_frequency", "communicationdata_campaign_description"]
  .some(id => document.getElementById(id).value.trim() === "")
```